# Auto running script without display

Tags: login

I have a pi3 which runs a script on login using /etc/profile.

The script receives wireless transmission on 433mhz from my remote and turns on a relay for 60 seconds. This is to activate an outside light shining up my driveway.

The script works fine and runs automatically when I have a keyboard mouse and screen plugged in.
When I moved the pi setup to attach it to the lights, it didn't function.
I remote connected to the pi using ssh and logged in, and then it started running the script and working properly.

So I guess there is something occurring to the auto-login being disabled when there is no HMI connected.

Is there a way to get around this??

Comment: /etc/profile is **NOT** for running scripts *# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))*

Comment: investigate systemd services - they are simple to set up - of course, you could use `/etc/rc.local` too if systemd is too complex for you

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/profile` script is available to do some configuration when login to a user session. It is a very bad place to start programs, except you need it to configure your user session. It only runs on login. The behavior is as expected. Your script runs either when login with keyboard/mouse/screen attached or when login by a ssh session.

You must use another start possibility but because you don't tell us when it should run I can't further help.